# Compare a deployed helm version to latest version

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, helm3

is there a way to run some kubectl commands that would compare a deployed helm version running in GKE on your cluster with a values.yaml to the latest released helm chart or a specific helm chart version (external helm chart e.g. prometheus)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using some command like `helm --dry-run`